# In casesensitive search by filter and include

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of code

```
let searchedListItems = searchableItems.filter(searchableItems => searchableItems.includes(this.state.userSearch))
```

where `searchableItems` is an array of strings

I want to get alle the values in the array into `let searchedListItems` and it all works - sort of...

My problem is that i need the include to not be case sensitive. Currently `Test` and `test` doesn't match up, but i need them to

Comment: there is a `toLowerCase()` function for strings in JS.  Given the line above, how do you think you would use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `toLowerCase` with the array elements and inputs:

```
let searchedListItems = searchableItems.filter(searchableItems => searchableItems.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.userSearch.toLowerCase()))
```